# Force IOS Object Same Size On All Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, scaling, cross-device

This is a little bit of an odd request, but I'm trying to create an app that has animations that go between screens. The issue I'm having is that when I tell the devices to create a UIView  35 by 35, it is different sizes on the iPad and the iPhone.

```
CGRectMake(0, 100, 35, 35);
```

So, my goal is to create a UIView of the exact same size on all devices. I tried looking into scale, but both devices have a scale of 2 when I tested them.

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].scale
```

They only appear to be slightly different in size, so I'm not sure what I need to do. Any thoughts or ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: By size, do you mean physical size like inches or cm?

Comment: Yes, to someone looking at the phone, I want the UIViews on both screens to appear exactly the same size if you held them next to each other.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is ppi. This one should help- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517356/getting-the-physical-screen-size-in-inches-for-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some old devices have regular display with 1х (like iPhone 3G), new devices have Retina displays (2x), and iPhone 6 plus has 3x retina display. And real pixel density (pixel per inch) is different (picture is from http://www.tekrevue.com/retina-display-comparison/):
[image]

i.e. view with size 35x35 on iPhone4 and iPad with Retina Display will be different in inches.